# How to add external URL in Yii

Tags: url, yii, external

How to give an external URL in Yii. I have tried the code, 
`<a href="<?php echo CHtml::normalizeUrl('/') . 'www.google.com'; ?>">Link</a>`
But it appends localhost with the URL. The URL is now coming as localhost/www.google.com

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the docs of `CHtml` says:

```
<?= CHtml::link('Link', 'http://www.google.com'); ?>
```